# Creating a method that accepts a string and a length (integer) as parameters

Tags: java

I am trying to teach myself more about the relationships between methods.  In doing this, I am writing a program that has multiple methods.  I have one method (createSpace) that is called from the main method.

It seemingly was straight forward but I realized I needed my createSpace method to

1) accept BOTH a string and an int as parameters, 
2) pad the parameter string with designated number of spaces and 
3) return a padded string.

Most of this seems pretty good to me.  For 2, I will write a for loop that gives the designated number of spaces that I want.  For 3, I will designate my method to be a return type.  But I am having a bit of trouble with 1, which is frustrating as it it the first part to this.

How does one create a method that accepts two types of values (strings and ints) as parameters?

Hopefully this question makes sense.

Comment: Please read a basic java tutorial on methods and method parameter lists.

Comment: I don't know if your getting mixed up in thinking you'd pass the String OR int as the same parameter? You'd need to pass them seperately, in the format `method(String var1, int var2)`. 

In terms of the padding, be aware that in Java, you can use the String concatenation operator (the plus) on an int, and it will treat the int as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You specify them like so, seperated with a comma:

```
public void genericMethod(int someNumber, String someString) {
    //dosomething
}
```

In case this wasn't clear, I would like to add the following. If you need two different strings, you specify two strings, also seperated by a comma:

```
public void genericMethod(int someNumber, String someString, String otherString) {
    //dosomething
}
```

Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply**, you can create a method with a String and int type parameters as follows:-

[your access modifier] [return type] [method name](set of parameters) {

// write your code here
}

**for example**, i will declare a method test with a string and int paramters which doesn't return any thing :-

```
public void test(String s , int i){
      // write your code here
}
```

and i recommended you to read this carefully http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm